# ICheck not working with bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table, icheck

I'm using iCheck(v1.0.2) jquery plugin for checkboxes with *Admin LTE* template.
*iCheck* is working fine except the bootstrap tables. While inspecting element in chrome developer tool I can find div created by the plugin inside the `<td>` but it isn't visible.

Here is the html

```
   <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>Functionality</th>
           <th>View</th>
           <th>Add</th>
           <th>Edit</th>
           <th>Delete</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>   
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>New Function</td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" class="icheck"></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" class="icheck"></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" class="icheck"></td>
           <td><input type="checkbox" class="icheck"></td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </div>
```

Jquery:

```
   <script>
     $(function () {
       $('.icheck').iCheck();
      });
   </script>
```

Developer tool:

[image]

Don't consider the console error. It's about the `favicon.ico`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Could please share your live link please.

Comment: Sorry.Its not hosted.Working on it in localhost.

Comment: There is any error throw by JS?

Comment: No error in JS and the necessary files are visible in source tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem on chrome while using datatables with iCheck and after searching for 3 hrs this is the only post I found discussing the issue. After researching around following did the trick for me.

you need to add relative position css to the element ins.

```
 $('.iCheck-helper').css('position', 'relative');
```

if you are using it inside column use it inside your rowCallBack.

```
$(nRow).find(':checkbox,:radio').iCheck();
$(nRow).find('.iCheck-helper').css('position', 'relative');
```

Hope it makes someones day easy.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `icheckbox` class `width`, `height` and `display` property

Example

```
width:20px, height:20px, display:inline-block;
```

Can you try it like this ?

Comment: I already tried giving height and width to the `div`.Its not working.

Comment: did you add display:inline-block; ?